Entity Framework Core update recursive json table column data if match some criteria
I need to update a JSON table column on migration but is a recursive object and is near impossible doing it using plain SQL.
I tried this in 2 ways:

Creating a stored procedure to do the migration and the recursive update over the json without success

Creating a DbContext on the "Up" migration and resolving the recursion using EF and C# code with success


My question is that seems to using DbContext inside a migration is not advisable, how can I solve this?

Try to make success with option 1. There is no possibility to access DbContext and even DbConnection inside Migration Up method. These methods are used to generate SQL script without any information about ConnectionString.
